# Optimal Collision Detection

Tags: collision-detection, collision, raycasting, raylib

I've been trying to find an optimal way to detect collision for an application I've been developing lately, here's the problem in the simplest context:

[image: A simple drawing a user has drawn]

The mouse positions in which the left mouse button was pressed are saved to a pointer which then when the left mouse button is released, is linked into a linked list structure (A Linked List Structure was preferred to a simple array because of the beneficial implementation ease of an Undo-Redo system) for example in the image above there are 3 different items in the list being: The always empty head and 2 pointers.

The lines between the yellow points are achieved by simply drawing line segments between every consecutive point.

[image: After the collision checks have ended]

The current and unwanted collision algorithm checks for collision between every yellow point and red line and colors the ones which were deduced to have been colliding into blue.

[image: Wanted Collision Detection]

What I want is to actually detect every intersection point of a red and a green line (Shown above) which by the means of the currently employed algorithm is impossible and I lack the necessities to further improve it.

What I ask of anyone willing to help is only to refer me to a couple of collision-detection algorithms which might be used to achieve the results I seek.

Thanks in advance.

If I was not deceived by my own perception a ray casting algorithm sounds like it could do the job but I wanted to hear some alternatives as well if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this never occurred to me before, but I just fixed it by checking collisions between the red lines and and the line segments marked by the consecutive yellow dots.

[image: Success]

Elaboration:

Each consecutive yellow dot pair forms a line segment which's function can be derived by many means, I then solve for the intersection points of the function by setting either the function to a certain y value (for the horizontal lines) or setting the x variable in f(x) to a certain x value (for the vertical lines).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).